# Is there any way to prevent deletion of certain files from user owned directory?

Tags: permissions, directory, rm

Let's say user has **Directory1** and it contains ***File1 File2 CantBeDeletedFile***
How to make so the user would never be allowed to delete the ***CantBeDeletedFile***?

If I change the ownership of **Directory1** and remove write permissions users wouldn't be able to delete any file. They also wouldn't be able to add new files etc.

I just want to be able to set some files which would never be deleted.

More specific description.

I am creating user profiles. I am creating application launcher files in their **Desktop**. So I want to set some launcher files (.desktop) and make them so user can only launch them and they couldn't rename nor delete, just launch.

Currently if user owns the directory which contain any file. He can delete.

If there is no generic way for all *nix, it's a Linux and ext4 FS.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

(I dislike intruding users' home, I think they should be allowed to do whatever they want to do with they homes… but anyway…)

This should work on linux (at least). I'm assuming `user` is already a member of the group `user`.
A solution is to change ownership of `Directory1` and set the sticky bit on the directory:

```
chown root:user Directory1
chmod 1775 Directory1
```

Then use:

```
chown root Directory1/CantBeDeletedFile
```

Now, `user` won't be able to remove this file due to the sticky bit¹. The `user` is still able to add/remove their own files in `Directory1`. But notice that they won't be able to delete `Directory1` because it will never be emptied.

—

<sup>1. When the sticky bit is enabled on a directory, users (other than the owner) can only remove their own files inside a directory. This is used on directories like `/tmp` whose permissions are `1777`=`rwxrwxrwt`.</sup>

Comment: I dislike too, but users are newbies to the Linux world. IF they delete a launcher coincidentally they are starting to spam our tech support :)

Comment: Thank it works! Not sure how will I proceed. With chattr or by this way. If do on your way. I still can delete the Directory as a root. With upper solution (chattr) even root can't delete the folder.

Comment: @bakytn: is this just a precaution or have you actually gotten the support call? Because most newbies probably will be too scared to mess with files they don't know.

Comment: @Lie Ryan 100% sure that they would call for support. But yes, currently it's just a precaution.

Comment: Sooner or later the training wheels have to come off... and if they haven't learned to ride the bike the accident will be something to behold. I agree with the answer, probably supplemented withcopious on-line help and canned spam "If you 'accidentally' deleted ThisDesktopFile, first go to the nearest wall and bang your head _hard_ against it 3 times (for luck), and then do `cp /here/is/the/master/ThisDesktopFile $HOME`. Signed: BOfH"

Comment: I have had a taste of `chmod 1775` and i really dislike that practice.  I am curious to this: would this be a better approach in creating another user and treat it as your "cloned user" and place the folder/file in there?

Comment: Have a protected copy owned by tech support, add a link, in users directory, to it. Provide a clickable script to restore the link.

Answer (score 75):

Make the file immutable with the `i` attribute.

```
chattr +i file.desktop
```

see `man chattr` for more information.

Comment: I add this note as I was unable to deduce it from the mentioned man page: `chattr` only works on ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems.

Comment: This is so cool! It worked! Thank you sir!
Elegant solution, but one limitation. Even root can't delete those files without first making it mutable. But this is so cool actually. Wasn't sure which answer to accept. Accepted more generic way but less fast

Comment: @manatwork it also works on XFS at least, I'd guess that some other filesystems also support these attributes.

Comment: To 'undo' this command, just do `chattr -i file.desktop`

Comment: @manatwork That's incorrect. I can confirm that it works on btrfs as well.

Comment: I just tested this on zfs on linux and it worked. I wanted to prevent deletion of a file used to instruct the backup program `bacula` to ignore the folder.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to prevent deletion of an individual file with Unix file permissions, but I can think of a workaround: write a daemon that replaces it when it is removed. `inotify-tools` is perfect for this sort of thing if you're on Linux.

There are a few ways you can replace the deleted item: copy a new one in place, or keep the real file in a safe place and just copy a link into the user's directory. For the link, you can either use a symlink or a hard link. I'd start with a symlink, but some (very few) programs don't handle symlinks correctly. If you find that the user encounters a program like this, use a hard link instead.

Answer (score 0):

A simple

```
chmod -i filename
```

will kinda "protect" that file from deletion.

```
rm filename
rm: remove write-protected regular file 'filename'?
```

You can still delete it, but at least you must be sure enough about what you're doing.

Comment: Which version of `chmod` does this apply to? Mine from GNU coreutils 8.25 does not support it.

Comment: I think you meant `-r`, not `-i`

Answer (score 0):

You asked about Linux specifically, but just for the benefit of other readers of these questions, BSD and macOS have [chflags](https://man.openbsd.org/chflags.1) which can also be used to completely protect the files (and not just from deletion).

The "uchg" flag is user-level. Users can also clear this flag themselves.

```bash
chflags uchg file-to-protect
```

There's also the "schg" flag, which is system-level. sudo is required to add or remove "schg".

```bash
chflags schg file-to-protect
```