# Prevent a user from removing file

Tags: linux, permissions

I am looking for a way so that a particular user or a group should not given the permission to remove any file in the system, but only read/execute the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is there any way to prevent deletion of certain files from user owned directory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20104/12779)

Comment: Not the duplicate. I am not asking for certain file, but for the whole system.

Comment: Mount the partition read-only. If that doesn't solve your problem, please elaborate why you want to do this. It appears very strange to me that I can create a file as a user and later when I decide that I no longer need that file I have no right to remove it.

Comment: @Marco, There are some users on my system who don't know anything about the PC, so they try to explore it for just learning purpose. My intention is that I can give them a separate account by which they can explore the system without accidently removing or changing any file on the system, but I as another user should be able to do any changes on the system.

Comment: How are they supposed to learn when they can't edit their `.bashrc` customize their programs, create cron jobs, etc? The solution is to provide the users with a facility to restore to an older working state (e.g. by using snapshots) when they messed something up. Document how the restore process works (e.g. a small howto) and they can mess with their files as they please and learn a lot without bothering you. Crippling the system is the wrong approach IMO.

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava That is the roughly way a Unix/Linux system normally works.  A user only has the right to delete or modify (a) files that he owns or (b) files for which a group that he is in has write permission.  The system administrator (that's you, I presume) has control over everything.   So, just make sure that these new users are in their own individual group.  If you want to be severe, do not give them ownership even of a home directory.  (They would still have write permission to `/tmp` but that shouldn't cause trouble unless they fill up the partition..

Comment: @Marco, they are not the programmers, but the normal desktop user who just want to view photos, surf internet, play music or videos. I don't want them to delete any data present on the system, they can only read or execute files.

Comment: @John1024, your comment is helpful. I will try that. You should have written it as answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> There are some users on my system who don't know anything about the
>   PC, so they try to explore it for just learning purpose. My intention
>   is that I can give them a separate account by which they can explore
>   the system without accidently removing or changing any file on the
>   system, but I as another user should be able to do any changes on the
>   system.

That is the roughly way a Unix/Linux system normally works. A user only has the right to delete or modify (a) files or directories that he owns or (b) files or directories for which a group that he is in has write permission.

The system administrator (that's you, I presume) has control over everything. So, just make sure that these new users are in their own individual group.

Unix was designed to be a *multi-user* system.  So, from the start, Unix/Linux give normal users only only limited permissions.  Generally, no normal user can mess with system files.  Only the system administrator, called `root`, can do that.

Some systems allow normal users to get root's capabilities by running `sudo`.  Make sure that your `/etc/sudoers` file does not give that capability to them.

If you want to be severe, do not give them ownership even of a home directory. They would still have write permission to `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` but that shouldn't cause trouble unless they create files so big that they fill up the partition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I got the path to where I should move on.

Answer (score 2):

After seeing your requirement , you can use the `setfacl` tool to restrict the access for some important files/directory(such as `/etc`, `/lib`, `/bin)`. So that new users will not be able to delete or modify any important system file .

Command :

```
setfacl -m u:{user_name}:{permission} {file/directory}
```

Restricting a learner from their home directory is not a good idea .

Comment: Important system file are read-only for regular users anyway so by default users *can't* modify an important system file, only their own files. So I don't know how this answers the question.