# Protecting files from rm -rf in writeable directory

Tags: permissions

Say, there is a directory `~/docs` with owner `boo` and group `boo` and permissions `rwxr-x---`. Assume there are important files `apple.txt` and `orange.txt` in `docs` which user `boo` wants to protect from himself (from accidental deletion, e.g. `rm -rf /home/boo/*`), but it's not an option to change permissions of `docs` to `r-xr-x---` or move the files. What possible solutions are there?

Normal users can't do `chattr +i apple.txt orange.txt` (and this is Linux-only anyway).

So the only option I can conceive of would be to first `chmod 550 apple.txt orange.txt` and then hardlink `ln ~/docs/apple.txt ~/docs/orange.txt ~/locked/` the files to a directory `~/locked/` and `chmod 550 /home/boo/locked/`. Is this right? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: This is a dupe of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20104/is-there-any-way-to-prevent-deletion-of-certain-files-from-user-owned-directory, which has a few good valid answers. Check it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're ruling out the normal methods of preventing deletion, so this calls for a workaround where deletion is possible but not catastrophic.

If `apple.txt` and `orange.txt` are symbolic links, then a stray `rm -rf` in that directory will only remove the symbolic links, not the actual data, so the symbolic links can just be re-created.

If for some reason the files can't be symbolic links then a fancier option would be to use a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem that performs a [union mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount) such as [funionfs](http://funionfs.apiou.org/?lng=en) or [unionfs-fuse](https://github.com/rpodgorny/unionfs-fuse). Put the important files in a branch other than the main branch so that deleting them will only hide them and not delete them from the underlying storage.

Of course, the most robust way of ensuring that the files aren't lost is to back them up. If you keep a history of the files and not just the latest version, this also protects against accidental overwrite (e.g. `>apple.txt` instead of `<apple.txt`). [Version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) (in a repository that's backed up!) is the ideal way of keeping a history of old versions.

Comment: But with symlinks one has to move the files out of the directory first. Using hardlinks avoids that.